# how to declare a global friend function that takes an nested class of a template class?

Tags: c++, templates, nested, declaration, friend

I have been trying all sorts of declarations but haven't got it right,getting all sorts of errors like syntax errors and linking errors.
this is the last attempt that made any sense to me.
 what am I doing wrong?

```
template<class T>
class Array
{
public:
  class Iterator
  {
  public:
    friend Iterator operator+<>(const int,typename const Array<T>::Iterator&);
  };
};

template <class T>
typename Array<T>::Iterator operator+(const int,typename const Array<T>::Iterator& it)
{
    return it;
}
```

and the main:

```
int main()
{
  Array<int> arr;
  Array<int>::Iterator it;
  it=5+it;
  return 0;
}
```

i get this error:

```
 error C2785: 'Array<T>::Iterator operator +(const int,const Array<T>::Iterator &)' and 'Array<T>::Iterator +(const int,const Array<T>::Iterator &)' have different return types
```

Comment: `void main()` is not legal C++.

Comment: you are right ...old habits die hard.

Comment: `your right` is not legal English there :P

Comment: well you are right again. but can you give me some advice on my code?

Comment: Those empty constructors and destructors are redundant.

Comment: true. but what i meant is can you give me some advice on how to make the function work?

Comment: If you do get the declarations working, you'll have another problem: that `operator+` function template can never deduce its template argument from function arguments.  So you would have to call it as `operator+<int>(5, it)`, which pretty much ruins the point of making it an operator.

Comment: why cant it deduce it from the template used to creat the array of which the iterator is a nasted class of? can you pls explain?

Comment: The left side of any `::` is an example of what the Standard calls a "non-deduced context", meaning template arguments that appear there don't get deduced.  This rule is because in general and with class template specializations, finding the correct answer could get uncomputable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one thing, `typename const Array<T>::Iterator` is wrong.  It should be `const typename Array<T>::Iterator`.  Since `typename` is for helping the compiler know what to do with something after a `::`, always put it immediately left of your `A::B::C` -type pattern.

You can't name a specialization of a function template as a `friend` before the general template has been declared.  And you can't declare that template until the type `Array<T>::Iterator` has been declared.

One thing you could do: Make the entire function template a `friend`, not just the one specialization.

```
template<class T>
class Array
{
public:
    class Iterator
    {
    public:
        template <class U> friend
        typename Array<U>::Iterator operator+(
            const int, const typename Array<U>::Iterator&);
    };
};

template <class T>
typename Array<T>::Iterator operator+(
    const int, const typename Array<T>::Iterator& it)
{
    return it;
}
```

It's a little bit sloppy in granting `friend`ship, but gets the job done.

Or, if you're willing to move the definition of nested class `Iterator` later in the file:

```
template<class T>
class Array
{
public:
    class Iterator;
};

template <class T>
typename Array<T>::Iterator operator+(
    const int, const typename Array<T>::Iterator& it);

template <class T>
class Array<T>::Iterator
{
public:
    friend Iterator operator+<T>(const int, const Iterator&);
};

template <class T>
typename Array<T>::Iterator operator+(
    const int, const typename Array<T>::Iterator& it)
{
    return it;
}
```

That takes care of how to declare and define them.  Unfortunately, this `operator+` is not easy to use, because of the details of template argument deduction rules....

I would probably try getting around this last issue by making `Iterator` a non-nested template:

```
namespace Array_detail {
    template <class T> class Array_Iterator;

    template <class T>
    Array_Iterator<T> operator+(int, const Array_Iterator<T>&);

    template <class T>
    class Array_Iterator {
        friend Array_Iterator operator+<>(int, const Array_Iterator&);
    };
}

template <class T>
class Array {
public:
    typedef Array_detail::Array_Iterator<T> Iterator;
};
```

Comment: thx mate! that was very helpful. one more question if you dont mind, why do you say it is hard to overload this operator? what should i do to avoid mistakes?